# Locating server for too long

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So, I have met a fellow player on Survival Games, we have had so much fun together. I told the person I would be on, but the server won't locate. How can this be if I was playing on the same server just the day before?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a server side problem, you may be able to try again later the connection might be successful. It could also be a client side problem, and rebooting your device may resolve the problem.